# Getting error when using Android Splashscreen with React Native

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, android-studio, splash-screen

How can I use Android's Splashscreen api with React Native ?

I tried online tutorials and getting below error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.guardapp/com.guardapp.MainActivity}: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStackFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception

I tried an online solution, that is remove `savedInstanceState` from `super.onCreate()` method

but that too gave me an error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.guardapp/com.guardapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException